# PS4 and TV link stopped working

Tags: monitor, ps4

I played the PS4 earlier today and didn't face any issues.

However I fired it up a few moments ago and all I get is a blank screen with flickering audio. The screen is permanently blank though, it tries to load the PS4 logo but it turns out skewed and scattered around the screen (for a very brief moment) then goes back to being blank.

What I've tried but didn't fix the problem :

- Changing HDMI cables
- Plugged in HDMI from a working device to the PS4; still blank
- Tried booting in safe mode; blank/flickering screen and audio
- Turned TV Off then back On
- Keep the PS4 running for a while

However now I noticed that this happens with one TV only. I tried connecting my PS4 to a PC Monitor and it ran fine !!

What could cause the TV to stop recognising the PS4 ? All HDMI ports do not provide visual output from the PS4. Also, the last update the PS4 received was for the playroom, not sure if it has anything to do with it. The camera is usually plugged in but I don't know if someone plugged it out or something before the issue appeared.

Comment: Did you ask this like a week ago too? I swear I saw it before...

Comment: "Plugged in HDMI from a working device to the PS4; still blank" Does this mean you moved an HDMI cable from, say a working PS3, to the PS4?  Basically, the TV's HDMI ports work with other devices, and the PS4 works with other TV's?  Perhaps provide the make/model of your TV?

Comment: @turbo Yeah the HDMI ports work with other devices, and the PS4 works on other TVs. It's just that particular TV and PS4 clashing ! My TV is the LG 55LW6510

Answer (score -1):

Remember that TV's these days are basically dumb computers with huge monitors.  If the PS4 is fine, it could be the logic board on the TV itself.

Comment: Any reason given for the downvote?